# Combined different csv to single xls

Tags: shell, unix

I want form an xls by combining three or more xls in shell script say in below example i have A.csv,B.csv and C.csv and i want all three in single xls..

```
File name:,A.csv,,,,,,
Load summary:,,,,,,,
,"(A)
Records received in CIF file","(B)
Records loaded in CIF table (temp_card)","(C)
Cramer count (Card)","(A - B)
Records failed to load into CIF","(B - C)
Records failed to load into Cramer",Cramer Load Success %,Overall Load Success %
,14606,14606,14606,0,0,100,100



File name:,B.csv,,,,,,
Load summary:,,,,,,,
,"(A)
Records received in CIF file","(B)
Records loaded in CIF table (temp_card)","(C)
Cramer count (Card)","(A - B)
Records failed to load into CIF","(B - C)
Records failed to load into Cramer",Cramer Load Success %,Overall Load Success %
,14606,14606,14606,0,0,100,100


File name:,C.csv,,,,,,
Load summary:,,,,,,,
,"(A)
Records received in CIF file","(B)
Records loaded in CIF table (temp_card)","(C)
Cramer count (Card)","(A - B)
Records failed to load into CIF","(B - C)
Records failed to load into Cramer",Cramer Load Success %,Overall Load Success %
,14606,14606,14606,0,0,100,100
```

How could i do that..

Comment: Please indicate expected output as well as what have you tried so far.

Comment: You are mixing .csv and .xls in your question, please indicate which output file format you desire as well (csv is textual, xls is a binary format).

Comment: I want these three csvs as different sheets in single xls say an xls for combined report of different element A,B and C

Answer (score 0):

What about something simple :

```
#!/bin/bash
cat A.csv B.csv c.csv > ABC.xls
```

That ought to do it . If you are expecting something else, then mention that in the QS .